# How to check if select tag has some value selected and get the value to send it by PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I want to check if the select TAG is selected and get that value to send it by PHPmailer

```
$clinica = '';


  if( !empty($_POST['clinica']) ){
    $clinica = ($_POST["clinica"]);
  } 
  else
  {
    $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">*Por favor escolha alguma clínica</label></p>';
  }


$mail ->Body = "
<h2 class=\"linha\"><p class=\"titulos\">clinica</h2>{$clinica} </p>"


<label>Clinica*</label>
              <div class="select">
                <select id="clinica" name="clinica[]">
                  <option selected disabled value="">Choose option</option>
                  <option value="<?php echo $clinica; ?>">Espinho</option>
                  <option value="<?php echo $clinica; ?>">Aveiro</option>
                  <option value="<?php echo $clinica; ?>">Braga</option>
                  <option value="<?php echo $clinica; ?>">Coimbra</option>
                  <option value="<?php echo $clinica; ?>">Guimarães</option>
                  <option value="<?php echo $clinica; ?>">Porto</option>
                  <option value="<?php echo $clinica; ?>">Viana</option>
                </select>
              </div>
```

I think is everything working fine, because he gives me error if i dont choose an option. But i can´t get the his value.
And when i submit he send the email but gives me this error 
'Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\IDC_website\includes\phpmailer.php on line 116'

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8gqU.jpg

In 'Clinica' instead of say 'Array', i need to get the value.
Someone knows what i am doing wrong?

Comment: WORKING! Just had to use the value name in the field value!
Instead of <?php echo $clinica; ?> , use 'Espinho', 'Aveiro' ... ''

Comment: Why not do the community a favor and show how you fixed by updating your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying this:

```
 <select id="clinica" name="clinica[]">
```

to :

```
<select id="clinica" name="clinica">
```

As you have made it hold multiple values (If you want multiple selection then add multiple attribute to select).
In jQuery you can check if it is empty or not , like this :

```
if($("#clinica").val()!==")
{
}
```

Comment: If i delete de [ ] from 'clinica' he can´t check if the value is there or not.

The validation is done, now my problem is just get the value and send it as string to my email.
I want to display the value selected on my body and not 'Array' as you can see in the image

Comment: If you want to convert array into string you can user arr.toString(); function.
This will convert your array into comma separated string.
In PHP you can explode the string using explode() function and then loop over that.

Comment: I understand that exist functions to convert, but can you give some pratical example please?
What i have to change in my function?

Comment: WORKING! Just had to use the value name in the field value! Instead of <?php echo $clinica; ?> , use 'Espinho', 'Aveiro' ... ''